Construct a triangle of base 9 cm and altitude 4 cm, the ratio of the other two sides beign 2:1
Please help me understand the principle behind this solution.
I assume AB||CD, and PC:CQ=AC:CD. But I can't find a way to prove either.


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I find it not very clear how P and Q are placed. It seems like an old textbook. However if you interpret 2. as "Place P in the middle of BC" then you are not very far away from finding that BC = CQ and then the parallelity. Once it's etablished I guess it is Thales' with extra steps (maybe some extra points which are symetric to others).

Segments $AB$ and $CD$ are $\bf{not}$ parallel to each other.  However, not only the triangle $ABC$, but also the triangle $BCD$ staisfies the mentioned requirements

@Qise I think $P$ and $Q$ are placed such that $BP:PC = BQ:CQ = 2:1$.

If you want to prove the validity of the given construction, show that $AM:BM =2:1$, where point $M$ is any point on the semicircle $PQ$.

The more I look at the solution, the less sense the grammar makes. Sorry for inflicting this on you. The question is genuine though. It is from IIT 1979 entrance (which often copied problems from Indian National Mathematics Olympiad). I know that coordinate geometry has a method that can find the vertices of such triangles, but the euclidean solution seems to be fake. But why would the question say "construct" if there is no euclidean solution? It is not hard to find the vertex algebraically.

For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, e.g., basic help on mathjax notation, mathjax tutorial and quick reference, main meta site math tutorial and equation editing how-to.

Probably you don't know what Apollonian circles are, see here: https://www.cut-the-knot.org/Curriculum/Geometry/ApollonianCircle.shtml All points $T$ of the circle constructed at point 3 have the property $TB:TC=2:1$.

Points $P$ and $Q$ are constructed such that $PB:PC=2:1$ and $QB:QC=2:1$.

And $P$ IS NOT the midpoint of $BC$ (the figure is a bit misleading).

OP has mentioned in his comment that he is sorry for inflicting this problem on us. Nobody needs to feel that way for posting a problem on this site. But OP’s opinion that the provided Euclidean solution seems to be fake is a mistake. The question says "construct", because there is a Euclidean solution. In our third comment, we hinted at one such solution, which we explain below.

Please pay attention to the diagram given above, in which $O$ is the center of the semicircle $PQ$ and $M$ is any point on its circumference. The perpendicular dropped from $M$ to the extended base $BC$ is $F$. For brevity, let $BC=3a, OF=b,$ and $MF=h$.
Since $P$ internally divides $BC$ in the ratio $2:1$, we have $BP=2a$ and $PC=a$. Point $Q$ externally divides $BC$ in the ratio $2:1$. Hence, we shall write $BC+CQ=BQ=2CQ$, from which it follows that $CQ=BC=3a$. Therefore, the diameter of the semicircle $PQ$ can be expressed as, $PQ=PC+CQ=a+3a=4a$. This means its radius $OM=2a$.
Now, we are in a position to apply Pythagoras theorem to triangle $OFM$ to express $h$ in terms of $a$ and $b$.
$$h=\sqrt{OM^2-OF^2}=\sqrt{4a^2-b^2}\tag{1}$$
Using (1), we can apply the same theorem to the pair of right-angled triangles $BFM$ and $CFM$ to calculate the lengths of $MB$ and $MC$ as shown below.
$$MB=\sqrt{BF^2+FM^2}= \sqrt{(4a+b)^2+h^2}=\sqrt{8ab+20a^2}=2\sqrt{2ab+5a^2}\tag{2}$$
$$MC=\sqrt{CF^2+FM^2}= \sqrt{(a+b)^2+h^2}=\sqrt{2ab+5a^2}\tag{3}$$
Expressions (2) and (3) shows that $MB=2MC$. Therefore, the distances to any point on the circumference of the semicircle $PQ$ from $B$ and $C$ are in the ratio $2:1$. The vertex $A$ of the required triangle can be located by drawing a line parallel to the base line $BC$ 4 cm from it to intersect the semicircle. Since there exists two such points of intersection, we have two solutions.
